# Resizing an image and keep the neighbours where they are?

Tags: jquery

I have 6 images next to each other in li elements. Now when I hover one of them, I want to resize that image. That works:

```
<img class="hoverific" width="35" height="35"  src="test.jpg" style="display: inline-block; width: 35px; height: 35px; overflow: hidden;">
```

CSS:

```
.hoverific {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(".hoverific").hover(function() {
  jQuery(this).stop().animate({
    width: 360,
    height: 360,

  });
}, function() {
  jQuery(this).stop().animate({
    width: 35,
    height: 35,

  });
});
```

This resizes the image I hover, but messes up everything around. I want a smooth resize of the hovered image using jQuery. Is the approach correct, or is there a better way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want us to help you solve an issue with things around this image, then you will need to show us the things around, including all relevant HTML and CSS.  Also describing what undesirable behavior you see and then describe HOW you want it to work better would make a big difference.

Comment: maybe you could create a fiddle that illustrates the problem

Answer (score 1):

A solution to your problem would be to change the margins of image that is being resized:

```
jQuery(".hoverific").hover(function() {
  jQuery(this).css("z-index",2).stop().animate({
    width: 360,
    height: 360,
    "margin-right": -325,
    "margin-bottom": -325,  
  });
}, function() {
  jQuery(this).css("z-index",1).stop().animate({
    width: 35,
    height: 35,
    "margin-right": 0,
    "margin-bottom": 0,
  });
});
```

The margin change of -325 comes from -360+35 (if the initial margins of the element is 0).
If the margins are not 0, then use -360 + 35 + the value of right (or bottom) margin.
Add `position: relative;` to your css for the z-index to work (if not, your expanding object may be partially covered by the others).